# How to change target .net framework in Visual Studio Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code to build a C# windows application which should target .net framework 4.5.2.
is that possible using visual studio code?

Currently I am trying to build the C# windows application in Visual Studio code but it is targeting .Net 5.

Thanks

Comment: just edit *.csproj file `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Answer (score 4):

In your project's folder, there is a file that has the name of your project and ends with `.csproj` open that file and inside you will find a `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` tag. If you just edit what's inside, then the target framework version will change.